# Do not changed background on login screen

Tags: kubuntu, sddm

Kubuntu 16.04 amd64.

Theme: Breeze

[image]

Choose png-file with resolution 1600x900 (it's my notebook resolution), apply. But on lock screen still see default blue background.

Why?

Comment: Bug 384222 - Do not changed background on login screen - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384222.
But really I'm get mistake. I forgot that login and lock screen has different settings.